# limit results of child/sub document when using find on master document

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

First time exploring mongoDB and I've bumped into a pickle.

Assuming I have a table/collection called `inventory`.
This collection in turn have documents that look like:

```
{
  "book" : "Harry Potter",
  "users" : {
              "Read_it" : {
                            "John" : <personal number>,
                            "Elise" : <personal number>
                          },
              "Currently_reading" : { ... }
            }
}
```

Now the dictionary "Read_it" can become quite large and I'm limited to the amount of memory the querying client has so I would like to some how limit the number of returned item and perhaps page it.

This is a function I found in the docs, not sure how to convert this into what I need.

```
db.inventory.find( { "book": "Harry Potter" }, { item: 1, qty: 500 } )
```

Skipping the second parameter to `find()` gives me a result in the form a complete dictionary which works as long as the "Read_it" document/container doesn't grow to big.

One solution would be to pull back the structure so it becomes more flat, but that isn't optimal in terms of other aspects of this project.

Is is possible to work with `find()` here or are there another function that can do this better?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to asking about projecting only specific elements of a nested structure.

Consider your document example (revised for use):

```js
{
    "book" : "Harry Potter",
    "users" : {
        "Read_it" : {
            "John" : 1,
            "Elise" : 2
        },
        "Currently_reading" : {
            "Peter": 1
        },
        "More_information": 5
    }
}
```

Then just issue as follows:

```js
db.collection.find(
   { "book": "Harry Potter" },
   { 
       "book": 1,
       "users.Currently_reading": 1,
       "users.More_information": 1
   }
)
```

Returns the result with just the fields specified:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5573b2beb67e246aba2b4b71"),
    "book" : "Harry Potter",
    "users" : {
            "Currently_reading" : {
                    "Peter" : 1
            },
            "More_information" : 5
    }
}
```

---

Not entirely sure, but that might not be supported in all MongoDB versions. Works in 3.X though. If you find it is not supported then do this instead:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "book": "Harry Potter" } },
    { "$project": {
        "book": 1,
        "users": {
            "Currently_Reading": "$users.Currently_reading",
            "More_information": "$users.More_information"
        }
    }}
])
```

The **`$project`** option of the `.aggregate()` method allows you to manipulate the document returned quite freely. So you don't even need to keep the same structure to return nested results and could change the result further if needed.

---

I would also strongly suggest using arrays with properties of sub-documents rather than nested dictionaries since that form is much easier to query and filter results than your current structure allows.

---

### Additional to unclear question

As mentioned, it is better to use arrays rather than keys to represent the nested data. So if your intent is to actually just restrict the "Read_it" items to a number of entries then your data is best modelled as such:

```js
{
    "book" : "Harry Potter",
    "users" : {
        "Read_it" : [
            { "username": "John",  "id": 1 },
            { "username": "Elise", "id": 2 }
        ],
        "Currently_reading" : [
            { "username": "Peter", "id": 3 }
        ],
        "More_information": 5
    }
}
```

Then you can do a query to limit the number of items in "Read_it" using [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) :

```js
db.collection.find(
    { "book": "Harry Potter" },
    { "users.Read_it": { "$slice": 1 } }
)
```

Which returns:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5574118012ae33005f1fca17"),
    "book" : "Harry Potter",
    "users" : {
            "Read_it" : [
                    {
                            "username" : "John",
                            "id" : 1
                    }
            ],
            "Currently_reading" : [
                    {
                            "username" : "Peter",
                            "id" : 3
                    }
            ],
            "More_information" : 5
    }
}
```

Alternate options use the projection [positional `$` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) or even the aggregation framework for multiple matches in the array. But there are already many answers here that show you how to do that.

Comment: The first option you gave will only return `key` with `value==1`, and I don't know their personal numbers in advance thus need to limit it to `500` matching any value in the `Read_it` field. Your second option looks promising and I found some examples but can't get that to work, it complains about `exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.` trying to use `$limit : 500` in my aggregate query.

Comment: @Torxed Read that last paragraph. And certainly not stated clearly in your question. If you are trying to limit a dictionary to a number or entries displayed then it basically cannot be done on the server without resorting to some arbitrary mapReduce code. It's brute force, and you are better off using arrays as suggested. Those at least are supported by the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) projection modifier.

Comment: I'll quote my original statement: *"I would like to some how limit the number of returned item"* - I did say that i wanted to limit the results to a certain number. I'll have another look at your edit in a second :)